# How do I declare a type with the same name as a global object in a namespace?

Tags: typescript

I want to type in a library with `foo.Proimse` that is a ponyfill of Promise.

But typescript compiler throws an error "Type alias 'Promise' circularly references itself" for this code:

```
declare namespace foo {
    var Promise: PromiseConstructor;
    type Promise<T> = Promise<T>;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20namespace%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20Promise%3A%20PromiseConstructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

I found a workaround with an alias:

```
type PromiseAlias<T> = Promise<T>;
declare namespace foo {
    var Promise: PromiseConstructor;
    type Promise<T> = PromiseAlias<T>;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20PromiseCopy%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20namespace%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20Promise%3A%20PromiseConstructor%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Promise%3CT%3E%20%3D%20PromiseCopy%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A

Is there any other clean solution?

Comment: This looks pretty clean to me! Ultimately you are using the exact same name so you need to alias it somehow. What do you not like about your solution?

Comment: It's better to refer the global object with the absolute name like `type Promise<T> = global.Promise<T>;`.

Comment: I don't think there are true absolute names in typescript, only scope local ones. Anything imported effectively gets aliases to a local name, it's just that the default local name is to adopt the original name. If you're looking for a strong signal that the promise you are referring to is the global one, I don't see that there is a quantitative difference if you just alias it to GlobalPromise or PromiseAlias. If there is, what is the alleged benefit of a 'cleaner' solution?